PostgreSQL Daemon Not Working
I'm having trouble creating a successful daemon. Before PostgreSQL went to naming their folders with an @ symbol, I had a working daemon, but now something, somewhere has changed that I can't figure out.
If I run:
sudo -u _systemuser /opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql@14/bin/postgres -D /opt/homebrew/var/postgresql@14

PostgreSQL starts fine.
However this plist doesn't work:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>homebrew.mxcl.postgresql</string>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>GroupName</key>
    <string>_systemuser</string>
    <key>UserName</key>
    <string>_systemuser</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/opt/homebrew/bin/postgres</string>
        <string>-D</string>
        <string>/opt/homebrew/var/postgres</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>

In LaunchControl, it says "This job has failed for no apparent reason."
So if I enable logging:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>homebrew.mxcl.postgresql14</string>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>GroupName</key>
    <string>_systemuser</string>
    <key>UserName</key>
    <string>_systemuser</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql@14/bin/postgres</string>
        <string>-D</string>
        <string>/opt/homebrew/var/postgres@14</string>
    </array>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/opt/homebrew/var/log/postgresql@14.log</string>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/opt/homebrew/var/log/postgresql@14.log</string>
</dict>
</plist>

I get the error "User _systemuser cannot write to the file: "file:///opt/homebrew/var/log/postgresql@14.log""
I've changed the permissions to those folders with:
sudo chown -R _systemuser /opt/homebrew/var/postgresql@14
sudo chgrp -R _systemuser /opt/homebrew/var/postgresql@14

However, using this logging plist does evoke a new error in LaunchControl:
2024-12-26 11:06:02.649106 <Error> Service could not initialize: posix_spawn(/opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql@14/bin/postgres), error 0xd - Permission denied

But as I said at the start, PostgreSQL starts up fine from CLI.
Stumped. Any ideas on what might be the problem?

AFAIR the @ is coming from Homebrew, to support installation of different Postgres versions in parallel. But can't you just start the daemon with brew services start postgresql@14?

That's what I've come to realise after a discussion with Linc. I was trying to run a Brew installed Postgres manually through my own plist, whereas I should have just been using brew services start. I'm now trying to un-break my brew install, because it's not starting postgres at the moment. I must have broken something while playing around with it.

Have you consulted brew doctor?

@JasonSalaz it says my system is ready to brew.

It looks like you changed the ownership of the wrong thing. You changed the directory /opt/homebrew/var/postgresql@14, but you need to create a regular file /opt/homebrew/var/log/postgresql@14.log and change its ownership to _systemuser:_systemuser. Better yet, you should create a subfolder of /opt/homebrew/var/log owned by the Postgres process user, and write the log file into that. If you do that, make sure to change the plist accordingly.

Thanks, I didn't see my mistake. However, it seems this issue is bigger than I thought. Now LaunchControl says it can't write to "file:///opt/homebrew/var/". So it seems like it can't access the var folder and also /opt/homebrew/opt << which is a shortcut to /opt/homebrew/Cellar/postgresql@14. The permissions to all these folders is set to my name. But somehow, if I run ($ sudo -u _systemuser /opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql@14/bin/postgres -D /opt/homebrew/var/postgresql@14) it runs under _systemuser without an issue!

I should amend the previous comment to mention that it can't access not /opt/homebrew/opt, but /opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql@14/bin/postgres as per before. But this is a shortcut to /opt/homebrew/Cellar/postgresql@14.

I'm not sure what is going on, but at a minimum, you have to make sure that the Postgres process has sufficient permission for all the files it needs to access. Remember that it's not enough to make a file readable if a directory in the path that leads to it is not readable. I don't use Homebrew, but I assume it provides a launchd plist as part of the Postgres package. Is that what you're using? Also, doesn't Homebrew have its own user forum?

I'm 90% sure it's permissions issue, but no, I created the plist myself.

May I suggest that you just get rid of the Homebrew stuff and use something more serious, such as this: https://www.postgresql.org/download/macosx/

Yer, I might do that if I can't get it working soon.

As per discussion with Linc, don't try to run PostgreSQL installed through brew manually/custom plist. Run it through brew services start.
